# How was the start date of the bronze age determined?

Tags: historiography, middle-east, bronze-age

Since the bronze age, it's been known that there was a bronze age, follow by an iron age.

Today it is accepted that the bronze age in the Middle East started about 3500 B.C. This date is easy to find through an internet search, but it is not backed up with a reference to how this date was determined.

Was it determined through carbon dating or by the depth of archaeological finds? And when was the approximate date set?

Comment: Generally, no one dating method is used - a variety of [methods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chronological_dating#Dating_methods_in_archaeology) are used to reach a consensus. For example, [this paper](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4164355/) focuses on radiocarbon dating, but references other papers which used different methods (historical and contemporary accounts, dendrochronology, crop seeds, etc).

Comment: The Early Bronze age was a very gradual thing, culminating in the middle Bronze age. It's not too important exactly when it started; wars were hardly being fought.

Comment: One point that should be made: Since it **by definition** relates to the use of specific metals (as opposed to other metals/stone), the "bronze age" started at different times in different areas. For example, sub-Saharan Africa went straight into the Iron age from the Stone age at about 900BC.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's break it down to two different parts:

- **method used** to determine age, i.e. a *[relative-dating system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relative_dating)* (*seriation*), the year should be **1816**
- **classification** of *[Three-Age System](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-age_system)*, the year should be **1836**

Wikipedia info on **[C.J Thomsen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christian_J%C3%BCrgensen_Thomsen)**.

So, the short answer is relative-dating, i.e. "*the depth of archaeological finds*" in the question. Carbon dating is *[absolute dating](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_dating)* which didn't exist then.

---

**On the Method of *[Seriation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seriation_(archaeology))*:**

CJ Thomsen used *seriation*. From *[A Dictionary of Archaeology](https://books.google.com.my/books?id=8HKDtlPuM2oC&pg=PA520&lpg=PA520&dq=seriation%20for%20bronze%20age&source=bl&ots=LK2ZTinKKN&sig=hJYbkRyCmCuZJWHJyQ03yYtTSi0&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=seriation%20for%20bronze%20age&f=false)*, p.520 - *emphasis mine*:

> Christian Jurgensen Thomsen (1788-1865) was the ***earliest exponent of seriation. In 1816, he began to use the method*** to organize the collection of pre-historic artefacts in the National Museum of Antiquities at Cophenhagen ...

---

**On Classification into Three-Age System:**

CJ Thomsen was the first to propose the three-age system in **1836** (other sources point to **1819**). He was an archaeologist, specialising in numismatics and developed the tripartite system according to the material (artifacts). As explained, this is relative-dating which resulted in ***culture and artifact classification***.

The date of *1819* is provided here - *[Encyclopedia of Archaeology (2007)](https://books.google.com.my/books/about/Encyclopedia_of_archaeology.html?id=RnoUAQAAIAAJ&redir_esc=y)*, p. 1020 - *emphasis mine*:

> It was however Christian Thomsen who first gave wide publicity to what has come to be called the three-age system, ***when in 1819 he arranged all of the prehistoric collections*** in the newly opened Danish National Museum into separate Stone Age, Bronze Age, and Iron Age assemblages. The three-age system was from the beginning both a culture classification and a kind of artifact classification.

However, **I believe the correct date should be later, closer to 1836** because:

1. Thomsen's guidebook for  National Museum of Denmark, *Ledetraad til Nordisk Oldkyndighed* (Guideline to Scandinavian Antiquity) on a method of classifying the museum’s archeological collections was published in *[1836](https://books.google.com.my/books?id=IWTGAAAAIAAJ&source=gbs_navlinks_s)* - *Google book* (also mentioned in Wikipedia article of Thomsen)
2. The date of 1836 in *[Origins and Revolutions](http://www.cambridge.org/us/academic/subjects/archaeology/prehistory/origins-and-revolutions-human-identity-earliest-prehistory?format=HB&isbn=9780521860024)* (Cambridge, 2007), p.12 - *emphasis mine*:

> the tri-partite division of the past that had existed ever ***since C. J. Thomsen, in 1836***, had ordered the collections of the National Museum in Copenhagen into cabinets containing stone, bronze and iron objects.

Comment: @danwag - You're welcome. And welcome to the site.